# Is there any fast ways to scrape a website with infinite scroll?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to use python to scrape a website implemented with infinite scroll. Actually, the web is pinterest. I know how to use selenium webdriver to scrape a web with infinite scroll. However, the webdriver basically imitates the process of visiting the web and is slow, much slower than using BeautifulSoup and urllib for scraping. Do you know any time efficient ways to scrape a web with infinite scroll? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite scroll is probably using an Ajax query to retrieve more data as you scroll. Use your browser's dev tools to inspect the request structure and try to hit the same endpoint directly. In this way you can get the data you need, often in json or xml format.

In chrome open the dev tools (Ctrl + shift + I  in windows) and switch to the network tab. Then begin to scroll, when more content is loaded you should see new network activity. Specifically a Ajax request, you can filter by "xhr". Click on the new network item and you will get detailed info on the request such as headers, the request body, the structure of the response, and the url (endpoint) the request is hitting. Scraping this url is the same as scraping a website except there will be no html to parse through just formatted data.

Some websites will try to block this type of behavior. If that happens I suggest using phantomjs without selenium. It can be very fast (in comparison to selenium) for mimicking human interaction on websites.

Comment: do you mean `selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS` or straight `phantomjs` in Javascript?

Comment: My preference is straight phantomjs because it involves less overhead, but honestly the difference is minimal when using it with selenium. Selenium + phantomjs is much faster than using a webdriver for a non headless browser.

Comment: @bspates I am a newbie. I don't quite the first method you mentioned (inspecting the request structure and hitting the same endpoint directly). Can you take the following url as an example and show me how to do it? [link](http://www.pinterest.com/cremedelacrumb/followers/)

Comment: @bspates Besides, is there a tutorial about the usage of selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS? I know nothing about Java, will it hurt when I use PhantomJS?

Comment: Selenium has client libraries in a bunch of languages, I found a Python one [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html).

Comment: @bspates Thank you. I tried what you said on a pinterest webpage. When I scroll down, I see lots of urls in the network tab with Get Method. I check out each of them but after I clicking on the urls there none of them gives meaningful contents. In such a case, should I say pinterest "blocks this type of behavior"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67857/discussion-between-peter-cao-and-bspates).